# Confusion about __main__ attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

Hi guys I had a question about one of the outputs to the terminal when the tests were ran: **test_eat_healthy (__main__.ActivityTests)** so the first bit I understand is the name of the function for the test, but then the **(__main__.ActivityTests)** I don't understand...what is does it mean or do on its own. I have my theories coming into this question, obviously **main** in this case is basically saying (the_name_of_the_file.ActivityTests) what I don't understand is what does **main**.ActivityTests actually do or mean, could someone explain?

```
import unittest
from unittest_file_1 import eat, nap

class ActivityTests(unittest.TestCase): 
    def test_eat_healthy(self):
        """
        eat should have a positive message for healthy eating
        """
        self.assertEqual(eat("broccoli", is_healthy = True), "I'm eating broccoli because my body is a temple")

    def test_eat_unhealthy(self):  
        """
        eat should indicate you've given up on healthy eating
        """  
        self.assertEqual(eat("pizza", is_healthy = False), "I'm eating pizza because YOLO")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

I obviously have another file as imported above, but that is not necessary for this question.

Comment: Can you clarify what you think the output should be and why? You write "why is it putting my class as an attribute to main, wouldn't it be a method" but a class is obviously not a method – it is a class.

Answer (score 0):

`"__main__"` ist the special name (`__name__`) of the main-module: this is the module that you pass to the python interpreter.
`"ActivityTests"` is the name of the class inside this module.